# Python - Evaluation order with a condition object

Tags: python, multithreading, conditional-statements

I'm trying to understand how a `condition object` works and I'm getting some seemingly very odd behavior from a small test program I've written. I've added a bunch of print statements to show the order in which the program lines are being executed.

I call a function `alert()` in a `thread` which asks the user to input a letter. If that letter is 'f' then this triggers the condition and alerts the program that condition has been met. To make it easier to visualize, the print statements from the program are indented while those from function are not.

```
import threading
import time

def alert():
    while True:
        letter = input("Input a letter:\n")
        print("letter == f:",letter == 'f')
        if letter == 'f':
            print("Enter if true branch")
            with cond:
                print("Enter cond notify block")
                cond.notify()
                print("notified cond")
                return 1


cond = threading.Condition()

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=alert)
thread1.start()

with cond:
    print("     Enter cond wait block")
    cond.wait_for(alert)
    print("     Alert triggered")

print("     Program finished")
```

Running the program I get the following results:

```
     Enter cond wait block
Input a letter:
f
Input a letter:
letter == f: True
Enter if true branch
f
letter == f: True
Enter if true branch
Enter cond notify block
notified cond
     Alert triggered
     Program finished
Enter cond notify block
notified cond
```

The output shows the program enters the condition block `with cond` and stops at the `cond.wait.for(alert)`, awaiting notification. The `alert()` function asks for a letter. I input 'f'. Then comes the surprising part. Before the next line (the `print()` statement) is evaluated, the `alert()` function has completed the whole `while` loop and is asking for another letter. How is this possible?

Even if the `alert()` function ran all the way through the `while` loop (maybe the `print()` statements are just slow) then it would have hit the `return` statement. Once `return` has been called why would the `alert()` function ever do another iteration through the `while` loop?

Then the last two lines of output show that the `alert()` function runs through the condition notification block `with cond` a second time. But this time the `return` statement works and ends the function because it doesn't ask for any more letters.